# What wrong with HttpServletRequest after .forward(req, resp)?

Tags: java, servlets, mocking, mockito

I have a test for simple Servlet which get `jsp` file. In this servlet action `request.setAttribute("key", "value")` but after call `.forward()` when I do `request.getAttribute("key")` I'm get `null`. Why this happen? This behavior determines `forward` or reason in mock object?

This is `doPost` of Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    final boolean success = addUserInDatabase(req);

    if (success) req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", EDIT_SUCCESS.get());//this write value
    else req.setAttribute("serverAnswer", ERR_UNIQUE_L_P.get());

    req.getRequestDispatcher(ANSWER.get())
            .forward(req, resp);
}
```

This is test:

```
//mock http.
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);


RequestDispatcher dispatcher = mock(RequestDispatcher.class);
when(request.getRequestDispatcher(ANSWER.get()))
                  .thenReturn(dispatcher);
servlet.doPost(request, response);
String result = (String) request.getAttribute("serverAnswer");//get value
Assert.assertThat(result, is(EDIT_SUCCESS.get()));// result == null
```

Why I get Null? Is it possible to get value of `setAttribute` after call `forward`? How to test this behavior? Thank You.

Comment: What do you think `req.setAttribute (..)` does when `req` is a mock?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I think he behaves like a real. But ... looks like no(((

Comment: It's a mock and you haven't stubbed its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `String result =  (String)req.getAttribute("serverAnswer");` just before calling `req.getRequestDispatcher(ANSWER.get())` on your servlet and check value of `result` it would still be null.

The reason is your request object is not real but mocked. you have to do something like this.

```
when(request.getAttribute(eq("serverAnswer"))).thenReturn(EDIT_SUCCESS.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

try `request.getAttribute("serverAnswer").toString();` and use `.include(request, response);`.

Comment: Do you think request.getAttribute("serverAnswer").toString(); works ??